# How to iterate a List and set data to it in most efficient way?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, java-stream

I am working on an issue, where i need to iterate an array list of N size and compare with another List and for all matching elements, i need to set some data on it. Example and what i tried so far is given below.

```
List<Emp> emp= new ArrayList<>(); 
List<Student> stud = new ArrayList<>();
 
class Emp -> int id, String status, String name; 
class Student -> int id, String studStatus, String name;
```

If the id of student and employee are matching then, update the emp status with some default value.

So far i tried this code, but it is not helping me to get the required result. Correct me what i am doing wrong here?

```
  stud.stream().filter(i -> emp.stream().filter(j ->
 j.getId().equals(i.getId()))
                                .map(i -> i.setStatus(Status.PASS)));
```

Comment: Please provide actual code rather than pseudo-code, and read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to hel p with formatting.

Comment: Using list iterator or even just a for loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: I have just formatted the code.. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to note in your code:

1. .filter should return a boolean so that it filters the record. But in your case that is not happening. You should take a count of the inner filter output and see if it is more than 0 or not. Alternately, simplify this and use anyMatch
2. .map expects a response of the same entity/class. But when you use a setter, you are returning void, hence your setter is not really taking effect. Either use a different custom setter that returns the updated object or else you use a block of code to return the updated object.
3. .map is not a terminal operation. Hence this entire expression is not even getting executed. You would want a terminal operation like collect, or even just a count to get the wheels in motion
4. Looks like you are using an enum for Status but that is not how the classes seem to be defined...

If you want to keep your code with corrections.. below is what you can do

```
    stud.stream()
        .filter(i -> emp.stream().filter(j -> j.getId() == i.getId()).count() > 0L) // ensure the outer filter is getting a boolean output
        .map(i -> {
            i.setStudStatus(Status.PASS);
            return i; // unless you return, the setter does not take effect
            })
        .count(); // terminal operation
```

If you are okay for slightly different approach and simplify the initial filter, and use a better way to terminate instead of map and count, then go by below (recommended)

```
    stud.stream()
        .filter(s -> {return emp.stream().anyMatch(e -> (e.id == s.id)); }) 
        .forEach(s -> s.setStatus(Status.PASS));
```

Comment: Don’t abuse `map` and `count` in this way. Java 9’s `count` implementation does already skip `map` functions when the size is predictable and future version may go a step further and skip `map` operations not required by a `filter` when the size is not predictable. Using `forEach` to perform an action is the the right approach. Besides that, not that there is no need to switch to a statement lambda form, `.filter(s -> emp.stream().anyMatch(e -> (e.id == s.id)))` would do the job.

Answer (score 3):

A `map` is an intermediate operation. The stream pipeline will not be invoked unless you attach a terminal operation to it.

To avoid the quadratic time complexity, do a pre-processing by constructing a `Map<Integer, Emp>`.

```
Map<Integer, Emp> empData = emp.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Emp::getId, Function.identity()));
```

This will throw an exception if there are more than one `Emp` object with the same `Id`.

Next, iterate through the students and get the appropriate `Emp` instance from the above map and change the status

```
stud.stream()
    .filter(student -> empData.containsKey(student.getId()))
    .forEach(student -> empData.get(student.getId()).setStatus(Status.PASS));
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is by first creating a set of all student ids like this:

```
Set<Integer> studentIds = stud.stream()
     .map(Student::getId)
     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

By using `Set` instead of `List` we also avoid duplicate ids.

Now we can iterate through the employees and see if the employee id is contained in the set of student ids. If so, we update the status of the employee.

```
emp.stream()
    .filter(studentIds::contains)
    .forEach(employee -> employee.setStatus(Status.PASS));
```

Comment: You should collect the employees’ IDs and then stream over the students to keep the original code’s logic, but otherwise, a very good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are not more efficient than the for-loops, so use:

```
    int studSize = stud.size();
    int empSize = emp.size();
    for(int i=0; i<studSize; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<empSize; j++) {
            if (stud.get(i).getId() == emp.get(j).getId) {
                stud.setStatus(Status.PASS);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```